# onChange / onInput alternatives?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a typing test page and running into a small issue.

I'm trying to start the timer when the user types, and using onInput works, but the problem is that it registers every time I type into the textArea which causes the starttimer function to repeat itself.

onChange works but it only works after I click outside the page which makes sense, but is not what im looking for. I need the timer to start as soon as the user starts typing. Also with onChange the stop function works, but the timer starts after i click outside of the page.

Is there a JS event that fits what i'm looking for, or is there a way to change onInput or onChange to fix the problem i'm having.

*JavaScript*

```
document.getElementById("test-area").onchange = function () {
      startTimer(1);
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: if I understand correctly you want the timer to start on the first character input?

Comment: For starting the timer, attach a separate input listener, which is executed only once, then stop the timer on onchange listener, and attach the once-input listener again.

Comment: add global variable `let StartedTimer=0;` then inside Onchange callback check `if(!StartedTimer){startTimer(1);}`

Comment: Adding `this.onchange = null` at the end of the `onchange` would solve it.

Comment: What you're looking for is a throttlilng feature: you can simply throttle how often the callback attached to the `input` event is called. There are plugins out there that serve that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `input` event because as you said `change` is only triggered after the input loses focus which is not what you want. You also need to handle the event only once.

```
document.getElementById("test-area").addEventListener("input", () => {
  startTimer(1);
}, {once: true});
```

Note that this removes the event handler after it is fired. If you need to run it again you will have to register the event one more time. Maybe in your timer callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:
The addEventListener() method attaches an event handler to the specified element.

```
document.getElementById("test-area").addEventListener("change", function () {
 if(!this.value.length){
    startTimer(1);
 }
}, {once : true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

#### Variant 1

Just create a flag:

```js
var timerStarted = false; // Was the timer started?
document.getElementById("test-area").oninput = function () {
      if(timerStarted) return; // If timer was started - do nothing
      startTimer(1); // Else - start the timer
      timerStarted = true; // Remember what we've started the timer
};
```

#### Variant 2

(A bit shorter)

```js
document.getElementById("test-area").addEventListener("input", function () {
      startTimer(1);
}, {once: true}); // Good thing about addEventListener
//                   With this it will run the event only single time
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I forgot about a flag lol. Flag fixes the issue of the timer restarting everytime I input something, however in my "matchText" method where the timer is supposed to stop after the user inputs the correct text doesn't anymore. I set the timerStarted to false and same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried onfocus ? its not exactly when they start typing but it works. Another option would be that you use onInput and on the clocks start function change a boolian -isRunning - to true. then put a if (isRunning) return. something like:

```
function start() {
  if(isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
}
```

and then change the boolian to false when you stop onChange

Answer (score 0):

Can you use JQuery? If so it has a method .one() which will execute the function only once. You can freely use keydown/keyup event handler then. For eg.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test-area").one("keydown", function() {
       alert("hey");
    });
  });
</script>
```